# How to append a disabled option to select using Option syntax

Tags: jquery

I am appending options to a select element and would like to make those options disabled if the condition is met. I have tried this:

```
if (myProp === "") {
    $.each(response,
        function(index, item) {
            myDDL.append(new Option(item.TextValue, item.valId).attr('disabled', true));
    });
}
```

But this results in an error, `Object doesn't support property or method 'attr'`.  I know I can do this by writing out the entire HTML option syntax, but I like the cleanliness of the code in my example.  Can this be done using the syntax I am using?

Comment: What about `$(Option(item.TextValue, item.valId)).attr('disabled', true)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attr()` is a method on a jQuery object. The `Option` object has a `disabled` property you can use instead:

```
if (myProp === "") {
  $.each(response, function(index, item) {
    myDDL.append(new Option(item.TextValue, item.valId).disabled = true;
  });
}
```

That being said, it's a little odd to mix jQuery and native JS in this manner. I'd suggest using one or the other, like this:

```
if (myProp === "") {
  $.each(response, function(index, item) {
    myDDL.append(`<option value="${item.valId}" disabled="disabled">${item.TextValue}</option>`);
  });
}
```

Comment: The second answer works, but the string interpolation is not working for me.  Any ideas on that?

Comment: That depends on which browser you're using as to whether it's supported. String concatenation would work just as well, only it's not as pretty :)

Comment: Right, so that isn't supported in IE 11?

Comment: No, not at all. Are you really using IE11?

Comment: Haha I have to since that is the browser the majority of my users are using unfortunately.

Comment: Ouch. Then yeah, string concatenation is the way to go :)

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Out of curiosity which browser do you prefer?

Comment: Personally I use Chrome, but it's a bit of a hog. Frankly anything that isn't IE or Edge is good. They're as bad as each other.

Comment: Hahaha I use Chrome personally, but unfortunately not in my profession.. but thank you for the information!